# Can I apply A-star algorithm in the map?

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm trying to use Google map API in java application. I just want to find the shortest path between two nodes. Can I apply A-star algorithm in it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218048/finding-shortest-paths-using-google-maps-for-a-large-number-of-nodes

Comment: Surely you have to know the network topology to perform any analysis? Where is that coming from?